# How to get the service endpoint registered behind the Application name in Eureka Server?

Tags: spring-boot, server, netflix-eureka

I have some web services registered at Spring Boot Eureka Server. Is there any way I can check the endpoints registered at Eureka Server, with respect to all the application?

*e.g:* [Eureka server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McN8W.png)

**Service1** means Request will be routed to service endpoint: *localhost:9080/service1*

**Service2** means Request will be routed to service endpoint: *localhost:9088/service2*

**Service3** means Request will be routed to service endpoint: *localhost:9085/service3*

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Eureka dashboard at http://host-name:8761 (Change the port if you're using a different one).

Secondly, Eureka doesn't route any request. It is just a service registry and keeps the records of the Microservices and its instances. You need an API Gateway (ZUUL) or similar to do the routing along with client side load balancers (ribbon, etc.).

You can configure the zuul endpoints in the application.yml (or properties) file like below to access your service endpoints.

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    service1:
      path: /service1/**
    service2:
      path: /service2/**
```

If you want to access the service1, then your endpoint will be something like `http://localhost:8765/service1/{custom-path}`

Note: 8765 is the default zuul port. Change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!!! @mephis-slayer I already have a zuul gateway setup, that uses ServiceId to resolve the endpoint from Eureka server. So what I need to know is once the zuul passes ServiceId to Eureka Server, what's the endpoint its getting to route the request?

Comment: I have something like this for routing through Zuul `zuul:
  retryable: false
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  routes:
   service1:
      path: /service1/**
      serviceId: service1` now I need to know if its getting the correct endpoint?

Comment: Updated the answer. let me know if it works and please update the question as well.

Comment: let me re-frame the question, I have a web service registered on eureka server with an application name Service1. and I have a zuul  gateway setup that points to Eureka server. I am hitting zuul end point, that depending on path url used the serviceID as Service1 and gets the actual web service endpoint from Eureka Server. and Routes the request to actual web service. Is it the correct flow or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Eureka - Just acts as a book keeper to which services has to register themselves. It polls for the registered services for availability and keep track of instances and services in the landscape. Zuul - Acts as the gatekeeper to the outside world by which the consumers will access your services. Ribbon (Does run separately) - Zuul uses ribbon to query the available instances and route the request to the appropriate service dynamically. If there are more than one instance available for the same service I'd, it does a client side load balancing before deciding on routing. Hope this clarifies :)

Comment: Sorry, if I am bothering too much, I am new to Zuul and Eureka and trying to implement it in my project. So its Ribbon that interact with Eureka Server to get the service instance, and I believe that instance should be having the actual web service endpoint. That in turns tell zuul where the input request should go.

Comment: Please refer here. There are numerous nice articles out there. https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-edge-serverapi-gatewayga

Comment: Thanks @mephis-slayer, let me check that out

Comment: Happy to help. Accept the answer if you're satisfied.